# Are people included in "flora and fauna" phrase?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Which sounds more correct:

1. Climate change affects the people, flora and fauna of the country.
2. Climate change affects the flora and fauna of the country.

Answer (score 3):

Merriam-Webster's online dictionary (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fauna) defines fauna as "animal life"; in a certain sense, that could mean people too, but "flora and fauna" is an established phrase that is not likely to be understood that way. I would mention people in addition to the flora and fauna.